`apt upgrade` throws many errors after upgrade to 24.10
This is a VirtualBox machine. It was running 24.04, previously upgraded through many (10+) "normal" Ubuntu versions with no major problem.
Today I upgraded it to 24.10 and after reboot the apt upgrade command started throwing many errors and does not complete:
# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oracular-backports InRelease
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

# apt list --upgradable
xdiagnose/oracular,oracular 3.8.10ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 3.8.10]
Notice: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

# apt upgrade
Upgrading:                      
  xdiagnose

Summary:
  Upgrading: 1, Installing: 0, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 0
  Download size: 0 B / 57.4 kB
  Freed space: 2,048 B

Continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 275942 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xdiagnose (3.8.10ubuntu1) over (3.8.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/systemd/system/failsafe-x.service.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:185: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\w'
  re_kparam = re.compile("^([\w\.]+)=(.*)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:195: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\w'
  re_kparam = re.compile("^([\w\.]+)=(.*)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:324: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
  re_xorg_error = re.compile("^\[\s*([\d\.]+)\] \(EE\) (.*)$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:325: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\['
  re_dmesg_error = re.compile("^\[\s*(\d+\.\d+)\] (.*(?:BUG|ERROR|WARNING).*)$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py:326: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\d'
  re_jockey_error = re.compile("^(\d+\-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+,\d+) ERROR: (.*)$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:105: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  re_param = re.compile("^\s*(\w+)\s*"+delim+"\s*(.*)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:105: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  re_param = re.compile("^\s*(\w+)\s*"+delim+"\s*(.*)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:133: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  p = re.compile("^\s*"+key+"\s*"+delim+"\s*(\"?)(.*)(\"?)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:133: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  p = re.compile("^\s*"+key+"\s*"+delim+"\s*(\"?)(.*)(\"?)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:133: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  p = re.compile("^\s*"+key+"\s*"+delim+"\s*(\"?)(.*)(\"?)")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:145: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  p = re.compile("^\s*"+key+"\s*"+delim)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:145: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'
  p = re.compile("^\s*"+key+"\s*"+delim)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/config_update.py:175: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\o'
  'BAR':                        'f(1&&2*$i^2) # \o/',
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/edid.py:67: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  re_head = re.compile("\(II\) .*\(\d+\): EDID \(in hex\):$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/edid.py:68: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  re_edid = re.compile("\(II\) .*\(\d+\):\s\t([0-9a-f]{32})$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/edid.py:287: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  regex = re.compile("\(II\) .*\(\d+\):\s+(.*)$")
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/pci_devices.py:97: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  PciDevice('i945g',      '(8086:2772|945G[ \/])',  [INTEL], gen='i945',      opengl='1.4' ),
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/pci_devices.py:99: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\/'
  PciDevice('i945gm',     '(8086:27a2|945GM[ \/])', [INTEL], gen='i945',      opengl='1.4' ),
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/utils/config.py:16: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\)'
  '''Yet another INI-style config file parser.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/xdiagnose/xorglog.py:94: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\('
  m = re.search('\(II\) Loading.*modules\/drivers\/(.+)_drv\.so', line)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

It is probably related to Python, but its version seems OK to me:
# python -V
Command 'python' not found, did you mean:
  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

# python3 -V
Python 3.12.7

Note that, I have encountered similar "invalid escape sequence" messages during the Ubuntu 24.04 → 24.10 version upgrade process too. (I don't remember the exact spot.)
Update
I tried to apt purge xdiagnose and apt install xdiagnose and this time I have the following errors:
Preparing to unpack .../xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xdiagnose (3.8.10ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/systemd/system/failsafe-x.service.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu1_all.deb
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Is xdiagnose incompatible with Oracular?

Seems it's not the first time this happens, here an older question which looks like the same problem. You should file a bug report.

No need to file a new bug. It's already at https://bugs.launchpad.net/xdiagnose/+bug/2083754 Simply select the link to mark it as affecting you also.
